# Laravel elixir 5.1 escapes chars with string interpolation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'm developing an app with laravel 5.1 and bootstrap. The problem is, when I use breadcrums, each separator has an addiotional char. It shows like this: `Item /\00a0 Item`. I discovered, the bootstrap sass has an interpolation to append this char to my separator. So, my question is, did I do something wrong or is this an elixir bug??

**EDIT**

The file _breadcrumbs.scss of bootstrap has this:

`content: "#{$breadcrumb-separator}\00a0";`

If I change that to

`content : $breadcrumb-separator + \00a0;`

It properly works. That's why I say it's an interpolation problem.

Comment: That character is a non-breaking space (in UTF-8). It should not cause any issues and should not even be visible on the page.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, you should file a bug report:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/f64fdc1e948152bbd975

Comment: Found a related issue: https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

It's a confirmed bug of [libsass#1115](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1115), a downstream hotfix was merged at [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/commit/47819e892fc0f2fa9c7269fdf297aa5e81a361c6) project, wait for the `3.3.6` release of bootstrap-sass.